# get last instance of model which contains request.user in manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to get the `last instance of model in which request.user in ManyToManyField`

I have tried using

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='post_likes')
```

views.py

```
def get_data(request):
    get_last_blog = Blog.objects.filter(likes__in=[request.user]).last()

    print(get_last_blog)
```

But it is showing first instance `not last`. I have tried without list like `likes__in=request.user` but it shows

> 'User' object is not iterable

I have tried many times but it is still not working. I am new in django. Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0):

.last() gets last or None object from queryset, so it's based on your order_by. I think you should be using .latest('<your_timestamp_field') and it will get latest object based on that timestamp field. Remember that .latest() can raise ObjectDoesNotExist exception if queryset is empty